# how can I draw on an image in flutter and get the new image back

Tags: image, flutter, drawing, paint

hello flutter community I need to draw free path like the red one shown in the screenshot any help ?

[image: the result I want]

Comment: use `GestureDetector`'s pan methods to get the path, draw it using `CustomPaint` and save the resultant image by wrapping it inside [Screenshot](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/screenshot) widget.